# How to get the most recent updated data from duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables. Table1 has the memberhsip id and joins to Tbl2 which has the enrollment id. Tbl3 has the data that I am interested in.
In a perfect world, a member should not have 2 enrollment id for the same date period; however, it does have it. 
I am interested in the most recent updated enrollment id. 
One of the criteria is the effective and term dates. For instance, if I am looking for effective and term dates 1/1/2018 to 2/1/2018, SQL will bring me 2 matching records for Member 1. How can I get the max of "Last Update" from the Tbl3.

Tbl1

```
Member iD
---------
|   1   |
---------
|   1   |
---------
```

Tbl2

```
|Member ID |  Enrollment ID |
|--------- | ---------------|
|    1     |        E1      |
|----------| ---------------|
|    1     |        E2      |
|---------------------------|
```

Tb3

```
---------------------------------------------|-------------------------|
| Enrollment ID | Effective Date | Term Date |       Last Update       |
|---------------|----------------|-----------|-------------------------|
|      E1       | 1/1/2018       |  2/1/2018 | 2018-01-19 11:20:03.483 |
|---------------|----------------|-----------|-------------------------|
|      E2       | 1/1/2018       |  2/1/2018 | 2018-01-19 13:28:20.923 |
|---------------|----------------|-----------|-------------------------|
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Do you really have a table with just IDs and no other columns? That seems very redundant.

Comment: @Lamu No, not really but this is the only way to explain my predicament. I need to start from that table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your intended output should be, and I haven't tested this without provided data- but you can edit the below as necessary in the select and it should give you the max Last Update date:

```
select * from 
(
select a.[member id]
    , b.[enrollment id]
    , c.[effective date]
    , c.[term date]
    , c.[last update]
    , row_number() over (partition by a.[member id] order by c.[last update] desc) row_num
        from tbl1 a
            join tbl2 b on a.[member id] = b.[member id]
            join tbl3 c on b.[enrollment id] = c.[enrollment id]
) x
where row_num = 1
;
```

Comment: Logically this looks close but the column names are syntactically wrong. To allow spaces and other horrific characters in column names you have to wrap them in [square brackets].